# Given an array/object of datetimes, how can I return an array/object of the times sorted by hour and times sorted by days of the week

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime, laravel

PHP/Laravel, I'm getting an array of objects that includes date times for each record.

I need to generate analytics on objects on an hourly basis of a day and daily basis of a week.

So for example:

For a date range of 1/1/2015 - 1/10/2015 I return 100 records all having date times.

Out of those 100 records, I need to compute analytics on how many times certain things happen in each hour of the day. So I'll need an object that returns all records that exist between, say, 1am - 1:59am, 2am - 2:59am, etc, so a structure like this?

```
{
    1 : {
        record1{},
        record2{},
        record3{},
    },
    2 : {
        record4{},
        record5{},
        record6{},
    }
}...
```

Then I need to also compute analytics on days of the week, so I'll need an object that contains records sorted by days of the week. So a structure like this.

```
{
    Monday : {
        record1{},
        record2{},
        record3{},
    },
    Tuesday : {
        record4{},
        record5{},
        record6{},
    }
}...
```

Comment: Where the data is coming from? Do you need only aggregates (counts) or data itself grouped by hour/day of week?

Comment: MySQL, but I'm trying to avoid more than a single call so lets just call the object static. I just need counts of occurrences, yes.

Comment: Post your array structure along with expected output

Comment: @GeorgeBöhnisch Does your records are Eloquent objects or plain array fetched from the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel's collection `groupBy` method to group your records for your needs.

```
$records = YourModel::all();

$byHour = $records->groupBy(function($record) {
    return $record->your_date_field->hour;
});

$byDay = $records->groupBy(function($record) {
    return $record->your_date_field->dayOfWeek;
});
```

Remember that this code to work, you have to define your date field in the `$dates` Model array, in order Eloquent to parse the date as Carbon object. If you did not then you can just use `Carbon::parse` in the function just before returning the result like this

```
$byHour = $records->groupBy(function($record) {
    $date = Carbon::parse($record->your_date_field);
    return $date->hour;
});
```

You can achieve the same thing without Carbon at all if you wish

```
$records = YourModel::all();

$byHour = $records->groupBy(function($record) {
    return date('H', strtotime($record->your_date_field));
});

$byDay = $records->groupBy(function($record) {
    return date('D', strtotime($record->your_date_field));
});
```

`groupBy` method will return collection of objects right in the format you want.

You can find out more information about Laravel collections [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/collections).